# Understanding leslie lamport's spacetime diagram with tick lines

Tags: distributed-systems, clocks

I am trying to understand tick lines in Fig 2 on Page 2 of "Time, Clocks, and the
Ordering of Events in a Distributed System" paper [1]. Below are 2 things which I did not understand

1. What is the relation between the total no of tick lines and the events on different processes? According to his explanation (i) there must be a tick
   line between any two events on a process line and (ii) every message line must cross a tick line. Did he choose the minimum number of tick lines which satisfied the above stated conditions for the events on different processes? Or did he choose an arbitrary number of tick lines Or something else?
2. Why is the spacing between tick lines un-even in that picture?

[1] https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Time-Clocks-and-the-Ordering-of-Events-in-a-Distributed-System.pdf

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a link to the paper. Some papers have several versions.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  We prefer that references fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible, and so others with the same question can find this via search. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard -- it would help to include title, authors, where published, and a link to a freely available pdf, if available. We have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!